# xpath loop pages with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

This is probably several questions in one but the person how can help me can probably answer them all so I write it as one question.

So, I want to get data for different products.

- Each product has several data points I would like to gather
- There are 30 products listed on each page
- There are hundreds of pages

I am using xpath to get the data but I have understood that it could be complex to use beautifulSoup together with Xpath.

Problems:

- I don't understand how to use beautifulsoup in my example when I am using xPath
- I have tried to loop pages with a for-loop and that worked fine. I then added elements with foundTitles.append([title.text]) but then I didn't got the dataframe to work. Probably because I don't understand how to put the new format into the dataframe.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent 

ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random

options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\aaaa.bbbbb\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
baseUrl3 = 'https://wwwwwwww/sok/?categoryLevel1=Vin&assortmentText=Fast%20sortiment&page=2'
driver.get(baseUrl3);

image = []
productlink = []
group = []
title = []
typeyear = []
description = []
fruktsyra = []
fyllighet = []
stravhet = []
country = []
volume = []
price = []
maltid1 =[]

content= driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='css-xzqcxb css-np3gtv']")
productlink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='css-10xvljd']")
group = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@class='css-16yusii']")
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@class='css-k091gg']")
typeyear = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@class='css-4hwyid']")
description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-uq1q8a']")
fruktsyra = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='css-ffxk30'][1]/div/div[@class='css-1q82610']")
fyllighet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='css-ffxk30'][2]/div/div[@class='css-1q82610']")
stravhet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='css-ffxk30'][3]/div/div[@class='css-1q82610']")
country = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-gl5xni']/span[2]")
volume = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='css-15am57e']")
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='css-tz3s9q']")
maltid1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-uq1q8a'][1]/span[@class='css-1wkn33'][1]")


product_data = {
    'image_url': image.get_attribute('src'),
    'productlink': productlink.get_attribute('href'),
    'group': group.text,
    'title': title.text,
    'typeyear': typeyear.text,
    'description': description.text,
    'fruktsyra': fruktsyra.get_attribute('aria-label'),
    'fyllighet': fyllighet.get_attribute('aria-label'),
    'stravhet': stravhet.get_attribute('aria-label'),
    'country': country.text,
    'volume': volume.text,
    'price': price.text,
    'maltid1': maltid1.text,
    }

df = pd.DataFrame({'image_url': image.get_attribute('src'),'productlink': productlink.get_attribute('href'),'group': group.text,'title': title.text,'typeyear': typeyear.text, 'description': description.text, 'fruktsyra':fruktsyra.get_attribute('aria-label'), 'fyllighet':fyllighet.get_attribute('aria-label'),'stravhet':stravhet.get_attribute('aria-label'),'country':country.text, 'volume': volume.text, 'price': price.text,'maltid1': maltid1.text},index=[0])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\aaaa.bbbbb\Documents\Python Scripts\sytemet_test2.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')

driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: seems like you are dealing with [https://www.systembolaget.se/](https://www.systembolaget.se/), please [edit] your question and include a sample of desired output instead of checking that long code manually.

Comment: I agree, it could have been shortened with less variables in this example. However I don't think a sample output necessarily will be more clear or describing. I tried to describe in the bullet list in the beginning that I am trying to get different data points from each product and the products are structured in a list on each page and then there are several pages. The output I would prefer to have in CSV where each product is a row and each attribute is a column. Was this clear or do you want me to create an output file in excel manually with some example rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need selenium or even beautifulsoup, all the content is being loaded via `xhr` requests without the need of javascript, as you can see on the network tab of the browser developer tools, i.e.:

```
import requests

h = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

u = "https://www.systembolaget.se/api/productsearch/search/sok-dryck/?searchquery=land&sortdirection=Ascending&site=all&fullassortment=1"

req = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()

for prod in req['ProductSearchResults']:
    ProductId = prod['ProductId']
    ProductNumber = prod['ProductNumber']
    ProductNameBold = prod['ProductNameBold']
    ProductNameThin = prod['ProductNameThin']
    Volume = prod['Volume']
    Price = prod['Price']
    Category = prod['Category']
    ProductNumberShort = prod['ProductNumberShort']
    TasteAndUsage = prod['TasteAndUsage']
    #...  and many other product details
    print(ProductNumber, ProductNameBold)
```

---

```
9001001 Evening Land Vineyard Seven Springs
7233401 Seven Springs
694701 Tyrrell's Wines
57801 Barceló
53701 Highland Queen
57802 Barceló
...
```

---

To retrieve detailed information about one or more  products, you can issue the following request:

```
u = "https://www.systembolaget.se/api/product/GetProductsForAnalytics"
d = {"ProductNumbers":["2048801"]} # use the ProductNumber(s) gattered above
prod_detail = requests.post(u, json=d, headers=h).json()
print(prod_detail)
```

---

```
{'Products': [{'ProductId': '303987', 'ProductNumberShort': '20488', 'Assortment': 'FS', 'CustomerOrderSupplySource': 'depot', 'SupplyCode': None, 'IsNewVintage': False, 'OriginLevel1': 'Skottland', 'OriginLevel2': 'Highlands', 'OriginLevel3': 'Western Highlands', 'OriginLevel4': None, 'OriginLevel5': None, 'BrandOrigin': None, 'BottleCode': 'Helbutelj', 'BottleTypeGroup': 'Helflaska glas', 'IsWebLaunch': False, 'Seal': 'Skruvkapsyl', 'VatCode': 1, 'PriceExclVat': 1199.2, 'PriceInclVatExclRecycleFee': 1499.0, 'PriorPrice': 0.0, 'ComparisonPrice': 2141.43, 'SellStartDate': '2008-04-01T00:00:00', 'SellStartTime': '10:00:00', 'BottleTypes': None, 'IsSellStartDateHighlighted': False, 'SellStartSearchUrl': '/sok-dryck/?sellstartdatefrom=2008-04-01&sellstartdateto=2008-04-01', 'ProducerName': 'Lang Brothers Limited', 'ProducerDescription': 'Familjen Edmonstone erhöll licens att destillera 1833. 1851 såldes destilleriet, under namnet Burnfoot, till MacLelleand som säljer det till Lang Brothers 1876, då under namnet Glen Guin. \n1905 blir det officiella namnet Glengoyne. 1965 blir Langs en del av Robertson & Baxter Group, som senare blir Edrington. 2003 köper företaget Ian Macleod & Co. destilleriet och varumärket Langs. Samtidigt byter man namn till Ian Macleod Distillers.', 'TasteAndUsage': 'Komplex, smakrik whisky med tydlig karaktär av sherryfat, inslag av valnötter, torkad frukt, kakao, lakrits och honung. Serveras rumstempererad som avec.', 'Production': None, 'CultivationArea': 'Glengoyne ligger i Western Highlands, alltså de västra delarna av Skottland. Gränsen för vad som räknas till de norra och västra högländerna brukar gå vid destillerier som ligger i nordvästlig riktning räknat från Staden Inverness.', 'Harvest': None, 'Soil': None, 'SupplierName': 'Cask Sweden AB', 'IsManufacturingCountry': True, 'IsSupplierTemporaryNotAvailable': False, 'IsSupplierNotAvailable': False, 'BackInStockAtSupplier': None, 'IsDiscontinued': False, 'IsCompletelyOutOfStock': False, 'IsTemporaryOutOfStock': False, 'RestrictedParcelQuantity': 0, 'IsRegionalRestricted': False, 'IsNewInAssortment': False, 'IsLimitedEdition': False, 'IsFsAssortment': True, 'IsTseAssortment': False, 'IsTsLsAssortment': False, 'IsHidden': False, 'IsSearchable': True, 'IsInAnyStoreSearchAssortment': True, 'IsStoreOrderApplicable': True, 'IsHomeOrderApplicable': True, 'IsAgentOrderApplicable': True, 'SeasonName': None, 'IsDishMatchable': False, 'IsDKI': False, 'AllergenStatement': 'Inga Allergener', 'IngredientStatement': None, 'AlcoholPercentage': 43.0, 'TasteSymbols': 'Avec/digestif;', 'TasteClockGroup': 'Ingen rökighet', 'TasteClockBitter': None, 'TasteClockFruitacid': None, 'TasteClockBody': None, 'TasteClockRoughness': None, 'TasteClockSweetness': None, 'TasteClockCasque': 8, 'TasteClockSmokiness': 1, 'IsCategoryBeer': False, 'IsCategoryBeerOrWhiskey': False, 'IsNewsIconVisible': False, 'Grapes': None, 'RawMaterial': 'Mältat korn av typen golden promise.', 'SugarContent': '<3', 'Additives': None, 'Storage': None, 'Preservable': '', 'HasInbounddeliveries': False, 'IsGlutenFree': False, 'IsEthical': False, 'EthicalLabel': None, 'IsKosher': False, 'Created': '2014-04-23T10:47:03', 'Modified': '2020-04-24T02:09:06', 'ShowAdditionalBottleTypes': False, 'OriginLevels': ['Skottland', 'Highlands', 'Western Highlands'], 'TasteSymbolsList': ['Avec/digestif'], 'IsTasteAndUsageAlone': True, 'ImageItem': [{'ImageUrl': 'https://static.systembolaget.se/imagelibrary/publishedmedia/rdxofqidiov294hwwqxz/303987.jpg', 'ImageAltAttribute': '303987'}], 'WebLaunch': None, 'ProductNutritionHeaders': [], 'HasProductImage': True, 'HasAnyTaste': True, 'HasSymbolsOrRecycleFee': False, 'HasTasteAndRestrictions': False, 'HasRestrictions': False, 'HasSymbols': False, 'HasAnyTasteClocks': True, 'HasAnyTasteSymbols': True, 'ProductNumber': '2048801', 'ProductNameBold': 'Glengoyne', 'ProductNameThin': '21 Years', 'PriceInclVat': 1499.0, 'IsOrganic': False, 'IsLightWeightBottle': False, 'Volume': 700.0, 'Vintage': 0, 'Country': 'Storbritannien', 'Category': 'Sprit', 'SubCategory': 'Whisky', 'Type': 'Maltwhisky', 'Style': None, 'BeverageDescriptionShort': 'Maltwhisky', 'StyleDescription': None, 'RecycleFee': 0.0, 'RecycleFeeIndicator': '', 'BottleTextShort': 'Flaska', 'IsAddableToBasket': True, 'IsFsTsAssortment': True, 'IsBSAssortment': False, 'IsPaAssortment': False, 'ShowAdditionalBsInformation': False, 'Usage': 'Serveras rumstempererad som avec.', 'Color': 'Brungul färg.', 'Aroma': 'Komplex, harmonisk doft med tydlig karaktär av sherryfat, inslag av torkad frukt, valnötter, lakritsfudge, pomerans och mörk choklad.', 'Taste': 'Komplex, smakrik whisky med tydlig karaktär av sherryfat, inslag av valnötter, torkad frukt, kakao, lakrits och honung.', 'AdditionalInformation': "Avec är drycker som konsumeras efter middagen till kaffet. Vanliga exempel på avec är whisky, cognac, mörk rom eller likörer. Ordet är franskt, betyder 'med' och är en kortform av uttrycket 'du café avec le petit verre' som betyder kaffe med det lilla glaset.  "}], 'StockBalances': []}
```

Comment: I know that there is an API and I have used it successfully. But for this test I would like to gather the data from the webpage instead of using the API, for several reasons (i.e. learn scrapping and gather data not part of the API)

Comment: I do not fully understand your example below. I checked in the network tab as you said and saw that it is xhr. But I don't understand where you get the the element-names from in your loop, do you fint it in the developer tool in the browser or do you mean that it is connected to the API?

Comment: You can analyze the `json` object on the developer tools console on the response of the `xhr` request, but I normally copy it to https://jsoneditoronline.org/ for better reading. I got the _the element-names_ from the xhr response.

Comment: Can you explain how you do with xhr in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Patric http://itman.in/en/ajax-request-monitoring-in-chrome/, it's for chrome but can be used on any modern browser.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I have been ill for a couple of days. I just tried it and it works fine. Thanks a lot! I really appreciate all the time you spent!! However I do not fully understand how it works with XHR. How do I initiate an AJAX call and how did you know that the html should be "https://www.systembolaget.se/api/productsearch/search/sok-dryck/?searchquery=land&sortdirection=Ascending&site=all&fullassortment=1"

Comment: By navigating on the website and monitoring the xhr requests on the network tab of the browser developer console.

Comment: Still don't find it. Which address are you standing on when you look at the XHR? If i use this "https://www.systembolaget.se/sok-dryck/?subcategory=R%C3%B6tt%20vin&sortfield=Name&fullassortment=1&pageto=2" and then monitor XHR I can't find this part anywhere "/api/productsearch/search/sok-dryck/". Another issue is that the response seems to stop at page 10, which means 300 products instead of 20.000. On the page i can walk further than 10 pages but the response seem to stop at 10, can I handle this in some way?

Comment: Re-posting the same link: [http://itman.in/en/ajax-request-monitoring-in-chrome/](http://itman.in/en/ajax-request-monitoring-in-chrome/)

Comment: For some reason I got diffrent responses now. I don't know if it could be that I cleared all cache, cookies and other stuff. However I found that thread now. Thanks!! Do you also have a suggestion to get around the limitation in objects in the response?

Comment: Try changing the search values while  browsing normally and see which values are used on the console. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I just solved it. There are two ways of looking at pages pageto=3 and page=3. "pageto" adds up all pages but limit the response to 300 objects. "Page" only respond with 30 objects but you can go as far as to page=332 before it stops you which means that if you loop it you will get almost 10.000 responses in total